# Wordpress: Using additional CSS chunk on button click

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, button, mobile

I'm currently developing a Wordpress-site and I need a mobile-version button to switch manually back and forth between mobile and desktop-version.

I have one .css-file with

```
    @media (pointer:coarse) {}
```

adding the mobile-version modifications (pointer:coarse detects if the device has a cursor).

Now I want to manually activate the modifications with something like:

```
    $('#Button').click(function(){
    ...
    });
```

The problem is that I don't know how to target big chunks of a .css-file.

Alternative solutions are always welcome!
If I'm unclear with something feel free to ask.

EDIT:
Thanks to Jignesh Sanghani for giving me the idea!
I put a class (.mobile) before every element I want to activate in mobile-mode and used the following code in a separate .js-file, but first here's the HTML code:

```
    <button id="mobileversion">Mobile-Version</button>
    <button id="desktopversion">Desktop-Version</button>
```

.js-code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$("body").removeClass("mobile");


if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  $("body").addClass("mobile");
var link = document.getElementById('desktopversion');
  link.style.display = 'block';
}

$('#mobileversion').click(function(){
$("body").addClass("mobile");
var link = document.getElementById('mobileversion');
  link.style.display = 'none';
var link = document.getElementById('desktopversion');
  link.style.display = 'block';
});

$('#desktopversion').click(function(){
$("body").removeClass("mobile");
var link = document.getElementById('desktopversion');
  link.style.display = 'none';
var link = document.getElementById('mobileversion');
  link.style.display = 'block';
});

    });
```

Now I have 2 buttons to switch between and I can hide one button with .css-code so only one is shown per website version.

Comment: I don't think you would be able to activate that media query using js - the point is that it is a media query and will automatically be activated depending on if the media query is met.

Comment: _“(pointer:coarse detects if the device has a cursor)”_ - that doesn’t necessarily make it a “mobile” device, you’re aware of that?

Comment: @CBroe Yes that's why I made a button to switch manually. What would you use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, The best option would be to have two sets of media queries which are only applied based on a parent class being present.

```js
$('#Button').click(function(){
  $("body").addClass("w600").removeClass("w768");
  });
```

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
 .w600 .myDiv {
  color: red;
 }
 .w600 .myOtherDiv {
  color: blue;
 }
}
@media (max-width: 768) {
 .w768 .myDiv {
  color: red;
 }
 .w768 .myOtherDiv {
  color: blue;
 }
}
```